# Iterate columns to show count between times

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to produce a result set from MySQL that will show me the count of lines at an interval throughout the day where the time is between start and end, so I can work out room utilisation by, say hour from 8.30 til 21.30.

The source data to prepare this is held in a table formatted as bellow (ie has session start and end time)

I can write some PHP to do this in lots of iterations, trying to work out if it can just be done directly in MySQL.

Source Table (Sample Data)

```
id  start_time            end_time               hostname          room
1   2018-10-19 16:28:37   2018-10-22 11:44:43    DESKTOP-FMVT2MJ   Room A
```

Example Desired output:

```
          8.30 9.30 10.30 11.30 ...
 Room A   0    3    4     2
 Room B   0    0    0     5
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: Two things are in your requirement, for your information. One is generating the result set with `room daytime count` columns, and the other is *pivoting* that result set to render each room in a row. In MySQL, pivoting is a notorious pain in the neck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivoting in MySQL is difficult because you have to create buckets for every instance of the column, which makes it quite long and repetitive. But if you really wanted to do it in MySQL and not php, then this would work:

TEST table structure:

```
id  start_time          end_time            hostname room
1   2019-01-01 06:30:00 2019-01-01 07:30:00 test1    Room A
2   2019-01-01 07:00:00 2019-01-01 07:30:00 test2    Room A
3   2019-01-01 08:00:00 2019-01-01 09:00:00 test1    Room B
4   2019-01-01 06:00:00 2019-01-01 09:00:00 test3    Room C
5   2019-01-01 06:45:00 2019-01-01 07:45:00 test2    Room B
6   2019-01-01 07:15:00 2019-01-01 08:55:00 test1    Room B
7   2019-01-01 08:15:00 2019-01-01 09:30:00 test2    Room C
8   2019-01-01 06:00:00 2019-01-01 18:30:00 test3    Room A
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    room,
    SUM(IF(6 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '6Hr',
    SUM(IF(7 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '7Hr',
    SUM(IF(8 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '8Hr',
    SUM(IF(9 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '9Hr',
    SUM(IF(10 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '10Hr',
    SUM(IF(11 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '11Hr',
    SUM(IF(12 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '12Hr',
    SUM(IF(13 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '13Hr',
    SUM(IF(14 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '14Hr',
    SUM(IF(15 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '15Hr',
    SUM(IF(16 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '16Hr',
    SUM(IF(17 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '17Hr',
    SUM(IF(18 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '18Hr',
    SUM(IF(19 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '19Hr',
    SUM(IF(20 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '20Hr',
    SUM(IF(21 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '21Hr',
    SUM(IF(22 BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(start_time,'%H') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(end_time,INTERVAL 1 SECOND),'%H'),1,0)) AS '22Hr'
FROM
    TEST
WHERE
    DATE(start_time) = '2019-01-01'
AND DATE(end_time) = '2019-01-01'
GROUP BY room
```

Result:

```
room    6Hr 7Hr 8Hr 9Hr 10Hr 11Hr 12Hr 13Hr 14Hr 15Hr 16Hr 17Hr 18Hr 19Hr 20Hr 21Hr 22Hr
Room A  2   3   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    0    0
Room B  1   2   2   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
Room C  1   1   2   1   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

This assumes each room `start_time` has an `end_time` on the same day it started.

I used an `IF` statement identify if a particular meeting row is `BETWEEN` certain hours, with each hour per bucket. For the `end_time`, if it ends at say 09:00:00, you don't want that to count in the `9Hr` bucket (since `BETWEEN` includes the ending range), so I took a second off it with DATE_SUB so it stays in the `8Hr` bucket. Since these have to be so rigid, if a row ends at 09:00:01, it will count in the `9Hr` bucket. This logic can be modified to suit your preference.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for the answer and the explanation, more convoluted (to do) than I had expected!